# Determine at run time if a control allows other controls to be added to it at design time

Tags: c#, controls, containers, design-time

I need to manipulate all controls on a form.  I'm fine with accessing the Controls collection to do this.  The problem comes with trying to include any controls contained within container controls such of `GroupBox` or `Panel`.  I could recursively iterate the each Control's own Controls collection but this then accesses all constituent controls for non-design time containers.

Since my non-container controls all manage their constituent controls' state based on the their own properties I don't to start messing with constituent controls.

How can I determine if a control is a design time container so that I can avoid process those that are not?

I've tried checking for the Designer attribute but this returns null for both the `ComboBox` and the `GroupBox`:

```
foreach(Attribute attr in typeof(ctl).GetCustomAttributes(typeof(Attribute), false))
{
    if(typeof(DesignerAttribute).IsAssignableFrom(attr.GetType()))
{
    DesignerAttribute da = (DesignerAttribute)attr;
    }
}
```

`ctl` is of type `Control` and in my testing is either `Combox` or `GroupBox`.

In both cases the `GetCustomAttributes` returns an array of 1 attribute which is the toolbox icon.

I've also tried checking assignability from to the `ContainerControl` class but they both are because, I assume, they will both contain controls at run time.

How do I detect a design time container?

Comment: Which control contains other controls which you don't want? I know only one - `PropertyGrid` and it's very easy to *exclude* it from recursion.

Comment: Any composite usercontrol.  I can't explicitly test for all possibilities.

Comment: `UserControl` only? Exclude all of them!

Comment: And what about usercontrols that act as design time containers?

Comment: Is there any? Subclassed `Panel` is not `UserControl`.

Comment: Right, ok.  So usercontrol is just an arbitrary term to indicate a control that is not derived from a .net standard control?

Comment: Very murky.  Every control has a Controls collection that you can add controls to.  It is perfectly valid to add a button to a text box for example.  The designer pays attention to the return value of Control.GetStyle().  When you drop a control on the design surface then it goes looking for a control that has the ControlStyles.Container style turned on.  That always at least ends at the Form.  It is a protected method, reflection required.

Comment: Thanks Hans.  Write that in an answer and I'll accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case Hans doesn't come back, and anyone is interested, this is my solution to the problem based on Hans Passant's suggestion:

```
    public static bool IsContainerControl(this Control ctl)
    {
        if (ctl == null)
            return false;

        MethodInfo GetStyle = ctl.GetType().GetMethod("GetStyle", BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance);
        if (GetStyle == null)
            return false;

        return (bool)GetStyle.Invoke(ctl, new object[] { ControlStyles.ContainerControl });
    }
```

Comment: Looks good to me.  Please close your question by marking your post as the answer.

Comment: Yeah, I can't yet.  There's some stupid 48 hour restriction on me doing so.

Comment: The reason I asked you to post an answer that I'd accept is that, as I understand it, this site grades its users on the quality of their answers.  You should definitely get credit for pointing me in the right direction.

Comment: I've been graded already, looks to me you'll have a lot more use for it than I do :)

Comment: LOL, so you have.  It doesn't show reputation on comments.  Those are big numbers. :)

Comment: Hans, can you possibly take a look at my follow up question. See below.

Comment: You can't do that, this is not a forum.  You need to click the Ask Question button again.