# Determine at run time if a nested control is a design time container

Tags: c#, controls, containers, design-time

Follow up question to [my previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21704752/determine-at-run-time-if-a-control-allows-other-controls-to-be-added-to-it-at-de/21727905?noredirect=1#comment32903535_21727905)

The 'TabControl' appears to work in a slightly odd way.
You have the 'TabControl' itself which is not a container, but a composite of several 'TabPage' controls which are containers.

My initial thought was, if the main control is not a container then iterate the child controls and recursively call my IsContainerControl function. However, this returns true for 'Panel' and 'GroupBox' controls that are child controls of both usercontrols and subclassed standard controls. I also tried checking for a Designer attribute on the child controls but these are present on in both cases.

Note that in these cases, the ContainerControl style set but the IDE does not allow controls to be dropped into them because they are not sited directly on the form. The question now becomes, what is the IDE checking on the TabPage controls to determine that you should be able to drop other controls on them?

Comment: What about using the Tag property of Control class to add custom data to the controls?

Comment: That might work, but is very messy and requires all subsequent devs to  know about it and remember to do it.  I'm looking for something generic and automatic.  The IDE can clearly tell the difference without tags so it is possible.

Comment: The IDE can tell using the property Component.DesignMode, but it might not work in dynamically added controls..
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.component.designmode.aspx